# how to use javascript to change background color on condition

Tags: javascript, if-statement, colors, background-color

hi everyone i'm new so please be nice:)

--edit 2: so this is what im onto now

```
    colorChange: function(data) {
    console.log(data.main.temp);
    var tempColor= this.displayWeather(document.querySelector(data.main.temp).value);
    if(tempColor<=10){
        document.body.style.backgroundColor="lightgrey";
    }
    else if(tempColor>=11&&tempColor<20){
        document.body.style.backgroundColor="lightblue";
    }
    else{
        document.body.style.backgroundColor="lightcoral";
    }
}
```

it seems the issue is that it's unable to find 'temp' and it's returning undefined to me when i try to console.log it.

thanks everyone for all your help before >.<

--edit: i have updated the code to this point but it still does not seem to be working, any help would be appreciated--

```
 colorChange: function() {
    if (temp.innerText<=10){
        document.body.style.backgroundColor="lightgrey";
    }
    else if (temp.innerText> 11 && temp.innerText<20){
        document.body.style.backgroundColor="lightblue";
    }
    else{
        document.body.style.backgroundColor="lightcoral";
    }
}
```

Comment: what is `data.main.temp`?

Comment: oh ok so i am using an api so the parameter is data (the data from openweather.org) and the constants of 'temp' and 'humidity' are stored in data.main sorry that was unclear!

Comment: in that case, `if (data.main.temp <= 20) { .....` should work. This line: `var tempColor = document.getElementById(data.main.temp).value;` doesn't really make sense, since `document.getElementById` is used to reference a DOM element by its id attribute

Comment: ok i understand your point, unfortunately the solution still did not work for me:( honestly im very new to this so i was just trying some things that seemed to work for others but now i see how that wouldn't make any sense haha and thank u for helping me

edit: ok so what happened was i originally had it as ".temp" as in the css element but then switched it to the code that it is now and forgot to take out getelementbyid and all that

Comment: just putting temp also did not work either ><

Comment: @niacode - Are you trying to get the value from your DOM? If `data.main.temp` is from the API, try `var tempColor = data.main.temp` or directly  `if (data.main.temp <= 20)`

Comment: ok i looked at it more and the issue seems to be that it cant find temp in the console? i did console.log to make sure it was looking for the right thing but it returned undefined >< do you know how i can get it to scan the temperature and then return the colors after?

Comment: @niacode if the `console.log` returns `undefined`, we should backtrack, and try doing `console.log(data.main)` and/or `console.log(data)` first, if it still returns `undefined`, we should then check how you fetched data from the API. Sorry I'm not familiar with openweather.org's API, I use a different one

Comment: @niacode - It seems to be a fetch issue, since `console.log(data.)` returns `undefined`. Also, refrain from posting your API Keys as seen from one of the links you provided

Comment: oh ok i will delete it then thank you >< sorry about that, i just wanted to be specific and and yeah it is definitely a fetch issue im just not sure how to fix it unfortunately :( thank you for all your help though

Answer (score 1):

In order for you to get the data, you have to fetch it from the API endpoint as follows

```js
    let colorChange = async function () {
        //const response = await fetch("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Denver&appid=API_KEY");
        const response = await fetch("https://api.open-meteo.com/v1/forecast?latitude=39.7392&longitude=-104.9847&daily=temperature_2m_max&timezone=GMT&forecast_days=1"); //Used other API for the temp
        const data = await response.json();
        console.log(data);
        //let tempColor = data.main.temp;
        let tempColor = data.daily.temperature_2m_max[0]; //I had to re-adjust to match other API
        if (tempColor <= 10) {
            document.body.style.backgroundColor = "lightgrey";
        }
        else if (tempColor >= 11 && tempColor < 20) {
            document.body.style.backgroundColor = "lightblue";
        }
        else {
            document.body.style.backgroundColor = "lightcoral";
        }
        document.querySelector("div").innerHTML  = tempColor 
    }

    colorChange()
```

```css
div{
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div>Temp goes here</div>
```

Don't forget to replace `&appid=API_KEY` with your API key

More information on fetch can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) and about async functions [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

I also added `&units=metric` as a parameter for you to receive it in Celsius

Comment: thank you so much for this and the documentations, unfortunately it is still giving me an error ", expected ts(1005)" at the asynchronous function line (sorry for all the responses/questions) (i know it's some kind of catch error just dont know what it means in detail)

Comment: @niacode - I attached a working snippet for you to check out. As for the error, can you share the whole error and your code? And is this browser javascript?

Comment: it says ',' expected ts(1005) [Ln 34 Col 9] at the line that creates the function let colorChange = async function () { and says it again at the line with the call for the function colorChange() at the end

Comment: @niacode - that opens a wide variety of causes, could you check if you double-declared the variable? `var colorChange ` , `let colorChange `, `const colorChange ` or `function colorChange`.  posting more parts of the code could help a lot

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript, functions are defined using `function name(params){ ... }`. If you want to grab an element from its class, you can use `document.querySelector(".class")`. This method grabs the first element on the page with that class though. But if you want a variable named that and not a DOM element, just type the variable as-is. I would also recommend putting your colorChange function in a loop or something else. Here is what your code would look like:

```
function colorchange(){
    var tempColor = data.main.temp.value;
    if (tempColor <= 20){
        document.body.style.backgroundColor="lightblue";
    }
    else if (20 < tempColor && tempColor < 40) { //I added this in to show you how you can add more conditions, using else if.
        document.body.style.backgroundColor="blue";
    }
    else {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor="red";
    }
}
```

Comment: thank u so much cole unfortunately this did not work for me but i think it would under the condition that the function would be able to "find" the temperature constant as it seems to be unable to do that at the moment (???) but thank u for this and suggesting the else if as well i was planning to add it in anyway once i got it working haha